# How To Insert Background Image in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okayy so heres my Problem, i have a column that is plain white right now and would like when the user hovers over the column, for it to transform into a picture, (background-image), this is what I'm doing:

```
$("#column2").hover(function() {
    $("#column2").css("background-image", "url(/Users/Atticus/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-09-18 at 7.37.06 PM.png)");
});
```

Comment: Did u try wrapping the URL to the image in `'`-quotes. It might be an issue with the whitespaces

Comment: Spaces are invalid in a URI ... check here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Comment: Ragdata is correct. I'd reccomend renaming your file to something a bit more memorable, rather than a random screen shot.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in jQuery, you can do `#column2:hover { background-image: url(...) }` in CSS.

Comment: The `.hover()` method needs a second argument to remove the background image when the mouse leaves.

Comment: Barman Your Right To!!! Thanks Much Love

Answer (score 2):

Add single quotes around the url:

```
$("#column2").hover(function() {
    $("#column2").css("background-image", "url('/Users/Atticus/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-09-18 at 7.37.06 PM.png')");
});
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Much Appreciated, Have A Good Night

Comment: No worries. Take note of the comments above. Especially the one about using CSS instead.